# Is it possible to define required arguments with a method annotation

Tags: java, spring-aop

I was to use a method annotation that defines some functionality to happen before a method is called (using aop). The problem I have is I can't figure out how to define required arguments that the before method will intercept, so I can only throw a runtime exception instead of catching missing arguments at compile time. Is there any way for a method annotation to define required arguments, or another workaround to the problem?

Comment: Directly, no. You can use a compile-time annotation processor, but that is non-trivial. The run time check is the easiest solution.